# How to create a new SharePoint add-in for Office Store (so no SPFX) that can use using Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, microsoft-graph, sharepoint-store

I am trying to develop a new SharePoint add-in (SharePoint hosted), that needs to use JavaScript to connect to Microsoft Graph API. Since it is use for Office Store, it should not use SharePoint Framework (SPFX).

Any idea how to handle authentication (ADAL/MSAL ?) for graph.microsoft.com from such a SP add-in ? and is it possible at all?

Comment: In SharePoint hosted addin and multitenant scenario (as you wish to distribute it through the store) I'm pretty sure it's not possible.

Comment: can you provide information, why, what/where is the limitation?

Comment: How to request an access token for graph? The only possible way (for SharePoint hosted add-in) is through the implicit oauth flow with adal.js for example. Implicit flow (and all other oauth flows) requires redirect url - the url which will receive your token via hash portion of the url. How to provide redirect url, if every url for SharePoint hosted add-in is different? You simply can't redirect back to your SharePoint hosted app web, because 1. you don't know url 2. azure ad app has limitations on an amount of redirect urls